# What is the first derivative of $y= \sin^2(\sqrt{x})$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find out what the graph of the function $y= \sin^2(\sqrt{x})$ looks like. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule? Have you plotted the function?

Comment: @Rasmus, I've just looked up the chain rule but I'm not sure how to apply it. And yes I've plotted the function on excel, but I need to know the mathematical boundaries of it.

Comment: Boundaries? Do you mean where the function is defined? $\sin$ takes all real arguments, and the square root function is defined for all non-zero $x$, so the domain is $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: adding to Billare, $\sin(x)$ gives values in $[-1,1]$, so $\sin^2(x)$ gives values in  $[0,1]$ and so does $\sin^2(\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 7):

The graph of $ y = \sin^2(\sqrt{ x }) $ on $x \in [0,15]$ from MATLAB is:

[image]

The first derivative of $\displaystyle y = \sin^2(\sqrt{ x })$ is $\displaystyle y^{\prime} = 2 \sin (\sqrt{ x }) \cos( \sqrt{x} ) \frac{1}{2}x^{ - \frac{1}{2} } $.

Simplifying gives $\displaystyle y^{\prime} = \frac{ \sin{ \sqrt{x} } \cos{ \sqrt{ x } } }{ \sqrt{x} }$.

Which means the *critical points* are (when the numerator or denominator is 0):

$ \sin{ \sqrt{x} } = 0 $

Due to the graph of $\sin(x)$:

[image]

you know that's whenever the argument (value given) to $\sin$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$:

$\displaystyle \sqrt{x} = k \pi $

$\displaystyle x = k^2 \pi^2,~~ k \in {I} $

Also when $ \cos{ \sqrt{ x } } = 0 $, which is when

[image]

$ \sqrt{x} = k \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

$ x = \dfrac{ k^2 \pi^2 }{ 4 },~~ k \in {I} $

So you can see the first critical point is when k=1, and then we have:

From the $\cos$ equation:
$ x = \dfrac{ k^2 \pi^2 }{ 4 } $

$ x = \dfrac{ \pi^2 }{ 4 } \approx 2.47 $

Which you can see is the first peak in the graph,

From the $\sin$ equation:
$ x = k^2 \pi^2 $

$ x = \pi^2 \approx 9.87 $

Which is the second peak in the graph, at about $x=10$.

Here's a larger graph for $ k \in [ 0, 100 ] $:

[image]

Comment: Very nice detailed answer!  Also, I would suggest to write \in for the $\in$ symbol instead of \epsilon.

Answer (score 4):

Apply chain rule twice to get:

$\displaystyle y^{\prime} = 2 \sin(\sqrt{x}) \cos(\sqrt{x}) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sin(2 \sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}.$

Now **note**, that the critical points is where $~~ 2 \displaystyle\sqrt{x} = \pi k,~~ k = 1,2,3,\ldots$.

Find the zeros and **note** that they are precisely the minimal values.

Comment: Shouldn't your answer be divided by $2\sqrt{x}$ instead of $2x$?   Also Chloe, note that shamovic used a trig. identity to change $2\sin (\sqrt{x}) \cos(\sqrt{x})$ into $\sin(2\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Right, thanks. Edited, That is what happens when you don't pay attention to what you write :)

Comment: @Brian, which trigonometric identity was that?

Comment: @Shamovic, why are the critical points where $ 2 \sqrt{x} = \pi k$, $k = 1,2,3,\ldots$ ? I could only find that y'=0 when y'=\frac{\sin(2 \sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} implying that x=0

Comment: Well if a fraction is $0$, than means that it's nominator is $0$. Now you must think when does the sine function obtain it's zeros.

Comment: @Chloe You have to enclose your $\TeX$ in `$` signs for proper display.

Comment: @Chloe $2\sin (x) \cos (x) = \sin(2x)$